# Menu items disappear on Microsoft Edge

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, microsoft-edge

I have just opened my Wordpress website in Microsoft Edge browser and I noticed that some of the menu links are missing. When I switch resolutions (different screens), different menu items disappear and the ones that disappeared before appear again. can't figure out why it happens, but here's the HTML code:

```
<section data-id="b5900dc" class="elementor-element elementor-element-b5900dc elementor-section-stretched elementor-section-full_width elementor-section-height-min-height elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-items-top elementor-section-content-top elementor-section elementor-top-section" id="headermedium" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;,&quot;background_image&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;&quot;}}" data-element_type="section" style="width: 1617px; left: 0px;">
                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-no">
                <div class="elementor-row">
                <div data-id="51e9713" class="elementor-element elementor-element-51e9713 elementor-column elementor-col-14 elementor-top-column" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                    <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                <div data-id="8ac116e" class="elementor-element elementor-element-8ac116e elementor-widget elementor-widget-spacer" data-element_type="spacer.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-spacer">
            <div class="elementor-spacer-inner"></div>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div data-id="1514061" class="elementor-element elementor-element-1514061 phone elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" id="phone" data-element_type="text-editor.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-text-editor elementor-clearfix"><img class="facebook" src="http://mayabarber.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Untitled-2.svg" width="33" height="33"> <img class="email" src="http://mayabarber.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Untitled-1.svg" width="33" height="33"> &nbsp;<span style="color: #61f6ff;">|&nbsp;</span><a style="color: #001a71;" href="tel:052-6582643">&nbsp;052-6582643</a></div>
                </div>
                </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div data-id="9ab21fe" class="elementor-element elementor-element-9ab21fe elementor-column elementor-col-14 elementor-top-column" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                    <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                <div data-id="708fd7b" class="elementor-element elementor-element-708fd7b elementor-widget elementor-widget-spacer" data-element_type="spacer.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-spacer">
            <div class="elementor-spacer-inner"></div>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div data-id="cbeafe4" class="elementor-element elementor-element-cbeafe4 menu-item elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="menu-contact" data-element_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#contact"><p dir="rtl"><span class="menu-item-text">צור קשר</span><span style="font-family: Heebo, sans-serif; font-size: 1.688em; font-weight: 500; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);"></span></p></a></h4>        </div>
                </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div data-id="a13b244" class="elementor-element elementor-element-a13b244 elementor-column elementor-col-14 elementor-top-column" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                    <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                <div data-id="7ee7b62" class="elementor-element elementor-element-7ee7b62 elementor-widget elementor-widget-spacer" data-element_type="spacer.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-spacer">
            <div class="elementor-spacer-inner"></div>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div data-id="ab1e386" class="elementor-element elementor-element-ab1e386 menu-item elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="menu-solutions" data-element_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#thesolutions"><p dir="rtl"><span class="menu-item-text">פתרונות</span><span style="font-family: Heebo, sans-serif; font-size: 1.688em; font-weight: 500; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);"></span></p></a></h4>       </div>
                </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div data-id="9142891" class="elementor-element elementor-element-9142891 elementor-column elementor-col-14 elementor-top-column" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                    <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                <div data-id="3b2d009" class="elementor-element elementor-element-3b2d009 elementor-widget elementor-widget-spacer" data-element_type="spacer.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-spacer">
            <div class="elementor-spacer-inner"></div>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div data-id="cab712b" class="elementor-element elementor-element-cab712b elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="menuu" data-element_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#fit"><p dir="rtl"><span class="menu-item-text">למי זה מתאים?</span><span style="font-family: Heebo, sans-serif; font-size: 1.688em; font-weight: 500; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);"></span></p></a></h4>      </div>
                </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div data-id="ca1c2c7" class="elementor-element elementor-element-ca1c2c7 elementor-column elementor-col-14 elementor-top-column" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                    <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                <div data-id="d9d4733" class="elementor-element elementor-element-d9d4733 elementor-widget elementor-widget-spacer" data-element_type="spacer.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-spacer">
            <div class="elementor-spacer-inner"></div>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div data-id="a80d715" class="elementor-element elementor-element-a80d715 menu-item elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="menu-about" data-element_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#aboutus"><p dir="rtl"><span class="menu-item-text">אודות</span><span style="font-family: Heebo, sans-serif; font-size: 1.68em; font-weight: 500; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);"></span></p></a></h4>       </div>
                </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div data-id="a517ba3" class="elementor-element elementor-element-a517ba3 elementor-column elementor-col-14 elementor-top-column" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                    <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                <div data-id="a7babfa" class="elementor-element elementor-element-a7babfa elementor-widget elementor-widget-spacer" data-element_type="spacer.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-spacer">
            <div class="elementor-spacer-inner"></div>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div data-id="95cd8d5" class="elementor-element elementor-element-95cd8d5 menu-item elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="menu-regulation" data-element_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#regulation"><p dir="rtl"><span class="menu-item-text">מהי רגולציה?</span><span style="font-family: Heebo, sans-serif; font-size: 1.68em; font-weight: 500; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);"></span></p></a></h4>     </div>
                </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div data-id="fedcaa1" class="elementor-element elementor-element-fedcaa1 elementor-column elementor-col-14 elementor-top-column" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                    <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                <div data-id="ccc474c" class="elementor-element elementor-element-ccc474c elementor-widget elementor-widget-global elementor-global-1281 elementor-widget-html" data-element_type="html.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <script src="https://cdn.enable.co.il/licenses/enable-L2054rm82dp9sv1-0618-4722/init.js"></script>      </div>
                </div>
                <div data-id="5ab854b" class="elementor-element elementor-element-5ab854b elementor-widget elementor-widget-global elementor-global-1284 elementor-widget-html" data-element_type="html.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() { 
jQuery('.menu-item-text').on('click',function(){ jQuery('.menu-item-text').removeClass('active'); jQuery(this).addClass('active'); }); 
});

</script>

            </div>
                </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#menu-contact, #menu-solutions, #menu-about, #menu-regulation, #menuu { 
text-decoration: none; 
color: #0B1B70; 
justify-content: center;
display: inline-block;
min-width: 60px;
max-width: 235.97px;
white-space: nowrap;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
} 

.menu-item-text {
    -webkit-transition: border 200ms ease-out; 
-moz-transition: border 200ms ease-out; 
-o-transition: border 200ms ease-out; 
transition: border 200ms ease-out; 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid transparent; 
border-top: 2.11px solid transparent; 
}


#menuu:hover .menu-item-text, 
#menuu:focus .menu-item-text, 
#menuu:active .menu-item-text{ 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
}
#menu-contact:hover .menu-item-text, 
#menu-contact:focus .menu-item-text, 
#menu-contact:active .menu-item-text{ 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
}

#menu-solutions:hover .menu-item-text, 
#menu-solutions:focus .menu-item-text, 
#menu-solutions:active .menu-item-text{ 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
}

#menu-about:hover .menu-item-text, 
#menu-about:focus .menu-item-text, 
#menu-about:active .menu-item-text{ 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
}

#menu-regulation:hover .menu-item-text, 
#menu-regulation:focus .menu-item-text, 
#menu-regulation:active .menu-item-text{ 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
}


@media (min-width: 1280px) {
  #menu-contact {

    }
}
    @media (max-width: 1280px) {
  #menu-solutions {
            left: 15px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1280px) {
  #menu-regulation {
      left: 30px;
}
}

    @media (max-width: 1280px) {
  #menu-about {
      left: 35px;
    }
    }
       @media (max-width: 1280px) {
  #menuu {
          left: 30px

    }
       }

@media (max-width: 1279px) {
  #menu-contact {
      right: 66px;
    }
}
    @media (min-width: 769px) {
  #menu-solutions {
padding (0, 20px, 0, 0)
  }
@media (min-width: 769px) {
  #menu-regulation {
margin-left: 65px;
}
}

    @media (min-width: 769px) {
  #menu-about {
margin-left: 45px;
    }
    }
       @media (min-width: 769px) {
  #menuu {
right: ;       }

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  #menu-contact {
      right: 66px;
    }
}
    @media (min-width: 769px) {
  #menu-solutions {
padding: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 769px) {
  #menu-regulation {
margin-left: 65px;
}
}

    @media (min-width: 769px) {
  #menu-about {
margin-left: 45px;
    }
    }
       @media (min-width: 769px) {
  #menuu {
margin-left: 0px;
    }
       }

              @media screen and (min-device-width: 1680px) 
              and (max-device-width: 1919px) 
           {
  #menu-contact {
margin-left: 42px;    }
}
    @media (min-width: 1680px) {
  #menu-solutions {
left: 14px;    }
}
@media (min-width: 1680px) {
  #menu-regulation {
right: 60px;}

}
@media (min-width: 1680px) {
  #menu-about {
right: 40px;}

}





    @media (min-width: 1920px) {
  #menu-about {
padding: 0px 60px 0px 0px;
    }
    }
       @media (min-width: 1920px) {
  #menuu {
padding: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
    }
       }
           @media (min-width: 1920px) {
  #menu-regulation {
right: 95px; 
}
           @media (min-width: 1920px) {
  #menu-contact {
left: 1px; 
}
    @media (min-width: 1920px) {
  #menu-solutions {
      left: 25px;
    }
```

Everything looks just fine on Chrome. I haven't checked Firefox yet, but I do want everything on the menu to appear on all browsers. It seems like everything else on the website appears ok there.
Here's the link to the website: [mayabarber.co.il](http://mayabarber.co.il)

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** Just need to remove width from CSS. please check attached screenshot. Once you removed the width then menu alignment will change.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgSNi.png)

**Solution 2:** Put below CSS in your main style.css

```
.elementor-166 .elementor-element.elementor-element-a13b244{ width:auto; float:left;}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried the second solution you suggested and it helped me with screens that have 1920 resolution, but not smaller screens like 1280. 
Removing the width will affect my chrome display and I wouldn't want that.